# Removing SOME line breaks from srt/txt file

Tags: awk, grep, line-breaks

I have a text file which has numbered entries, a timecode and a transcript. I am trying to remove the line breaks in the transcript and leave the others. I'm trying to use grep or awk.

File is like

> 1
>   00:00:27,160 --> 00:00:29,054
>   Sometimes there's not much dialogue.
>   
>   2
>   00:00:30,100 --> 00:00:31,090
>   But other times there is quite a bit, 
>   and it's formatted into two lines
>   
>   3
>   00:00:31,500 --> 00:00:33,700
>   I want to remove the line breaks only on
>   these long lines, leaving all other formatting.
>   
>   4
>   00:00:33,805 --> 00:00:37,285
>   So that all dialogue ends up being on a single
>   line no matter how long that line.

Output would look like:

> 1
>   00:00:27,160 --> 00:00:29,054
>   Sometimes there's not much dialogue.
>   
>   2
>   00:00:30,100 --> 00:00:31,090
>   But other times there is quite a bit,
>   and it's formatted into two lines
>   
>   3
>   00:00:31,500 --> 00:00:33,700
>   I want to remove the line breaks only on
>   these long lines, leaving all other formatting.
>   
>   4
>   00:00:33,805 --> 00:00:37,285
>   So that all dialogue ends up being on a single line no matter how long that line.

thanks to all who have provided help

Comment: Seems like you could pull out text between a number and double newline then remove newlines from that string and put the new string back in.... as long as there is always a number and double newline between entries

Comment: The syntax error is because you added `>` signs at the start of each line of the awk script. Don't do that.

Comment: formatting error. tried your method again and it works like a dream. thank you v much

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't rely on lines starting (or not) with any specific characters - just attach the 4th and subsequent lines in each record to the end of the 3rd line of that record:

```
$ awk '
BEGIN { RS=ORS=""; FS=OFS="\n" }
{
    print $1,$2,$3
    for (i=4;i<=NF;i++)
        printf " %s", $i
    print "\n\n"
}
' file
1
00:00:27,160 --> 00:00:29,054
Sometimes there's not much dialogue.

2
00:00:30,100 --> 00:00:31,090
But other times there is quite a bit, and it's formatted into two lines

3
00:00:31,500 --> 00:00:33,700
I want to remove the line breaks only on these long lines, leaving all other formatting.

4
00:00:33,805 --> 00:00:37,285
So that all dialogue ends up being on a single line no matter how long that line.
```

Comment: +1 I agree, better not to have any dependencies where it's not needed.

Comment: hey, have just tried this on a file without success...maybe i'm doing something wrong... If you're interested, this is the subtitle file i'm testing it out on, but really any subtitle file will do to test on: [subtitles srt file](http://www51.zippyshare.com/v/73945719/file.html)  Thanks for your help

Comment: You'll need to be more specific about what "without success" means if you'd like help debugging it. And I'm not going to go off clicking on links looking for other input, just update your question with a specific input sample, the expected output, the command you ran, the actual output you get and any error messages.

Comment: Here's what i get when i run the above script:    MACPRO:~ homedirectory$ awk '
> > BEGIN { RS=ORS=""; FS=OFS="\n" }
> > {
> >     print $1,$2,$3
> >     for (i=4;i<=NF;i++)
> >         printf " %s", $i
> >     print "\n\n"
> > }
> > '  /Users/homedirectory/Desktop/subs_test.srt  >/Users/homedirectory/Desktop/subs_test.srt
awk: syntax error at source line 2
 context is
  >>> > <<<  BEGIN { RS=ORS=""; FS=OFS="\n" }
awk: bailing out at source line 9

Comment: Don't try to post input, output, or scripts in a comment as it cannot be formatted legibly. As I said - update your question. All I can see from what you posted in the above comment is that you're getting a syntax error so chances are you got the copy/paste of my answer wrong but I can't tell if all of those ">" symbols are actually part of what you typed or what the line numbers were or anything else about it.

Comment: have done that now - this is my first time using stack exchange so sorry for poor practice. thanks for your help man.

Answer (score 0):

Delete all new lines that are preceded by a letter or a space or tab:

```
perl -pe 's/([a-zA-Z \t])\n$/$1/'
```

Comment: I think this kind of works, thanks. It merges the two lines of dialogue into one long one - perfect! But it also seems to get rid of other line breaks - i'm ideally looking for a  way to keep those all intact e.g. keep the blank lines etc...

Comment: afraid not. Logically, it should work perfectly: the deletion of only line breaks preceded by a letter is exactly what i'm after...thanks btw

Comment: I've tweaked my answer to allow some white space at the end of the line. Does that help?

Answer (score 0):

I think you need something like

```
awk '/[0-9]+/,/^$/{ if(NR<3) print $0; else {while($0!=""){ printf $0;next; }}}' file
```

It's not working, but you may get the idea.

Comment: thanks. i'm still making sense of grep/awk/perl/regex but i'll see if i can work out what's going on here - it seems promising.

Comment: Only use range expressions like `/[0-9]+/,/^$/` if you want to get from the first occurrence of the start of the range to the last occurrence of the end of the range (ie. not what we need here). Otherwise they make simple tasks slightly briefer but even slightly complicated ones very difficult without a complete re-write.

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this with `awk`:

```
awk '!NF{print}/[a-z]/{printf "%s ", $0;next}1' file
```

```
$ cat file
1
00:00:27,160 --> 00:00:29,054
Sometimes there's not much dialogue.

2
00:00:30,100 --> 00:00:31,090
But other times there is quite a bit,
and it's formatted into two lines

3
00:00:31,500 --> 00:00:33,700
I want to remove the line breaks only on
these long lines, leaving all other formatting.

4
00:00:33,805 --> 00:00:37,285
So that all dialogue ends up being on a single
line no matter how long that line.
```

```
$ awk '!NF{print}/[a-z]/{printf "%s ", $0;next}1' file
1
00:00:27,160 --> 00:00:29,054
Sometimes there's not much dialogue.

2
00:00:30,100 --> 00:00:31,090
But other times there is quite a bit,  and it's formatted into two lines

3
00:00:31,500 --> 00:00:33,700
I want to remove the line breaks only on these long lines, leaving all other formatting.

4
00:00:33,805 --> 00:00:37,285
So that all dialogue ends up being on a single line no matter how long that line.
```

Comment: Thanks again. just noticed this works great for the example provided, but when applied to a .srt subtitle file (formatted identically to example), the first letter of every dialogue line gets lost..?! I'm gonna look into it... Just in case you immediately knew what was going on, i thought i'd pass it by ya...

Comment: @user5268 Did you import this file from Windows? Looks like your file has `^M` characters. Do a `dos2unix` to your `srt` file and run the command. `dos2unix` will remove those `^M` chars.

Comment: I wouldn't do this as it'd fail if the 4th line of any record started with `I` or any other upper case letter (e.g. a name) or a number or punctuation marks or if the 3rd line started with a lower case letter.

Comment: @EdMorton True, but I didn't anchor the regex. Assumed as long as it had some text it should be pulled up. But having said that, I agree, your solution is much better.

Comment: Ah, I see, that's not so bad then, it'd only fail on lines that don't contain lower case letters (or some upper case depending on locale) which doesn't occur in the OPs sample input so maybe it's fine.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and wrote this little code, which solved my problem:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
FILE *quelle,*ziel;
int i;
long maxsub,count,tmp,sub;  
char puffer[10][200], *ptr,line[400];

if(argc != 3)
    {
    printf("Usage: srtlinejoin Filename CountOfSubtitles\n");
    return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }   

maxsub = strtol( argv[2], &ptr, 10);

if( (quelle=fopen(argv[1],"r")) == NULL) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Can't open %s\n", argv[1]);
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }
if( (ziel=fopen("out.srt","w")) == NULL) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Can't open out.srt\n");
    fclose(quelle);
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

//read and write first line
fgets(puffer[0], 200, quelle);
fputs(puffer[0], ziel);

for(count=1; count < maxsub;count++)
//for(count=1; count <= 3;count++)
    {
    //printf("Processing subtitle %d\n",count);

    tmp=0;
    //Read and write time
    fgets(puffer[0], 200, quelle);
    fputs(puffer[0], ziel);

    do  {
        fgets(puffer[tmp], 200, quelle);
        //Scan for next Subtitle
        sub = strtol( puffer[tmp], &ptr, 10);
        tmp++;
        }
    while(sub != (count+1));

    //Der Untertitel hat nur eine Zeile
    if (strlen(puffer[1]) == 2)
        {
        fputs(puffer[0], ziel);     //New Subtitle
        fputs(puffer[1], ziel);     //Next empty line
        fputs(puffer[2], ziel);     //Next number
        }

    //Der Untertitel hat zwei Zeile
    if ((strlen(puffer[1]) > 2) && (strlen(puffer[2]) == 2))
        {
        for(i=0;i<400;i++)
            line[i]=0;

        strncpy(line,puffer[0],(strlen(puffer[0])-2));
        strcat(line," ");
        strcat(line,puffer[1]);
        fputs(line, ziel);      //New Subtitle
        fputs(puffer[2], ziel); //Next empty line
        fputs(puffer[3], ziel); //Next number
        }

    //Der Untertitel hat mehr als zwei Zeile
    if ((strlen(puffer[1]) == 2) && (strlen(puffer[2]) == 2))
        {
        printf("Attention: The subtitles has more than two lines\n");
        }
    }

printf("Check last subtitle!\n");

fclose(quelle);
fclose(ziel);
return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```